# How can I make the most of my toddler's love of books?

Tags: toddler, working-parents, books

My son is almost 2 and loves books.  He has free access to about 20 baby/toddler books when he is at home, and often looks through them, carries them around as he plays or requests to be read to.  I don't really give him library books as he is still occasionally destructive (usually accidental, I think normal for his age).

Because both parents work full time and we live a generally busy life, I don't have as much time as I would wish to read to him and encourage his love of books. I do spend at least a few minutes a day reading to him, usually re-reading one of his favorites for the hundredth time.

What are some creative (and/or proven) ways to nurture his interest and love of books, and make the most of his limited reading time-- both academically and just in terms of making things fun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are doing the right things. Reading to a child is just about the best way there is, and making it a daily thing is important for a child. Wanting the same thing read for the 100th time is also very common. In time he will want more variety.

(Side note: the book ["Thud"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thud!) by Terry Pratchett has the Chief of Police make an iron rule that he *will*, come rain, shine or tentacular monstrosity, be home at 6pm to read "Where's My Cow" to his toddler son).

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are doing is right now is right. I would also recommend you supplement your child's reading with audio books.

I loved books as a kid too, but my working parents didn't have enough time to read to me. I'm dating myself, but my parents gave me just a ton of stories on tape. I learned on to use the cassette player and I used to listen to the stories before bed or when I couldn't sleep. It was nice because I had stories in Mandarin and English which helped me stay bilingual.

Answer (score 0):

Read to them often and keep the I interest going to the point they can read alone. My daughter had read 100s of books by the time she was 7 years old. As a kid I don't think I read 5 books through middle school. It makes a huge difference!!